# flatten and compact an array more efficiently

Tags: ruby

On many occasions, we need to perform two or more different operations on an array like `flatten` and `compact`.

```
some_array.flatten.compact
```

My concern here is that it will loop over the array two times. Is there more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, there are *many* more efficient ways, from rolling your own loop to using C++ instead of Ruby. The question is: Why do you care? Is this actually some kind of bottleneck?

Comment: You can loop manually or get a lazy enumerator (assuming all the methods you want to use are in `Enumerable`).

Comment: Ruby is intended to be used pragmatically, part of which means "focus on the problems that matter".  If your concern is that you need to iterate more quickly over an array, use C.

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: You could modify the code that produces `some_array` to not generate array-of-array which causes you to use `flatten`, and not contain `nil`s which causes you to use `compact`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually think this is a great question. But first off, why is everyone not too concerned about this? Here's the performance of `flatten` and `flatten.compact` compared:

[image: flatten performance]

[Here's the code I used to generate this chart, and one that includes memory.](https://github.com/mooreniemi/experiments/blob/master/lib/flatten_plot.rb)

Hopefully now you see why most folks won't worry: it is just another constant factor you're adding when you compose a `flatten` with a `compact`, maybe it's valuable at least theoretically to say: how can we shave off the time *and space* of this intermediate structure? Again, asymptotically not super valuable, but curious to think about.

As far as I can tell, **you can't do this by making use of `flatten`**:

Before looking at the source, I hoped that `flatten` could take a block like so:

```
[[3, [3, 3, 3]], [3, [3, 3, 3]], [3, [3, 3, 3]], nil].flatten {|e| e unless e.nil? }
```

No dice though. We get this as a return:

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, nil]
```

This is weird in that it basically tosses the block away as a no-op. But it makes sense with the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L4533). The C method `flatten` used in Ruby's core isn't parameterized to take a block.

The procedure in the Ruby source code reads kinda weird to me (I am not a C programmer) but it's basically doing something like depth first search. It's using a stack that it adds every new nested array in to process that it encounters. (It terminates when none remain.) I've not calculated this formally, but it leads me to guess the complexity is on par with DFS.

So the source code could've been written such this would work by allowing for extra setup if a block is passed in. But without that, you're stuck with the (small) performance hit!

Comment: btw if you REALLY REALLY want to be able to do this, i wrote a C extension that adds a new function `collapse`: https://github.com/mooreniemi/array_collapse

Answer (score 1):

It is not iterating over the same array two times. `flatten` creates in general an array that has an entirely different structure from the original one. Therefore, the first and the second iteration are not iterating over the same elements. So, it naturally follows that you cannot do that.

Comment: true, but it just means the loop is of some constant smaller the second time, it'd still be more efficient to do it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is one layer deep, then the arrays can be merged in a set.

```
require 'set'
s = Set.new
Ar.each{|a| s.merge(a)}
```

Comment: You are relying on the set not to change the order of the elements.